# EF Core 5 Violation of PRIMARY KEY with migrations

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-5.0

Let's say we have an entity Country with some fields (CountryCode, CountryName, CountryCode2 and CountryNumberCode).

We've created a IEntityTypeConfiguration for the Country entity and then seeded the table with a couple of records:

```
builder.HasData(new Country[]
  {
      new Country { CountryCode = "ARG", CountryName = "Argentina", CountryCode2 = "AR", CountryNumberCode = 32 },
      new Country { CountryCode = "URY", CountryName = "Uruguay", CountryCode2 = "UY", CountryNumberCode = 858 }
  });
```

Then we generate a migration, this creates the two InsertData in the Migration Script.

```
            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                table: "Countries",
                columns: new[] { "CountryCode", "CountryCode2", "CountryName", "CountryNumberCode" },
                values: new object[] { "ARG", "AR", "Argentina", (short)32 });

            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                table: "Countries",
                columns: new[] { "CountryCode", "CountryCode2", "CountryName", "CountryNumberCode" },
                values: new object[] { "URY", "UY", "Uruguay", (short)858 });
```

Update the database and my two records are in place.

Let's suppose the user access the application and realise that there's no chile in the database and decides to add it.

So now the Countries table contains the records, 'ARG', 'URY' and 'CHL'.

So far so good.

Some time later we realise that we need to add Chile, and Brazil to the seed, couse we start selling to a lot of chilean friends, and so we add thowse records to the IEntityTypeConfiguration. It looks like this:

```
builder.HasData(new Country[]
  {
      new Country { CountryCode = "ARG", CountryName = "Argentina", CountryCode2 = "AR", CountryNumberCode = 32 },
      new Country { CountryCode = "URY", CountryName = "Uruguay", CountryCode2 = "UY", CountryNumberCode = 858 },
      new Country { CountryCode = "CHL", CountryName = "Chile", CountryCode2 = "CL", CountryNumberCode = 152 },
      new Country { CountryCode = "BRA", CountryName = "Brasil", CountryCode2 = "BR", CountryNumberCode = 76 }
  });
```

We create a new migration, this creates two new InsertData in the Migration Script.

```
            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                table: "Countries",
                columns: new[] { "CountryCode", "CountryCode2", "CountryName", "CountryNumberCode" },
                values: new object[] { "CHL", "CL", "Chile", (short)152 });

            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                table: "Countries",
                columns: new[] { "CountryCode", "CountryCode2", "CountryName", "CountryNumberCode" },
                values: new object[] { "BRA", "BR", "Brasil", (short)76 });
```

And here comes trouble.

When me update the database we get the following error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Countries'. Cannot insert
> duplicate key in object 'dbo.Countries'. The duplicate key value is
> (CHL). The statement has been terminated.

We've created the script to see what went wrong and saw both statements

```
INSERT INTO [Countries] ([CountryCode], [CountryCode2], [CountryName], [CountryNumberCode])
    VALUES (N''CHL'', N''CL'', N''Chile'', CAST(152 AS smallint))
INSERT INTO [Countries] ([CountryCode], [CountryCode2], [CountryName], [CountryNumberCode])
    VALUES (N''BRA'', N''BR'', N''Brasil'', CAST(76 AS smallint))
```

Is there a way to change the migrations behaviour so that it wount add the new Chile record if it doesn't already exists?

Edit:

```
    public class CountryConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Country>
    {
        private const string TableName = "Countries";

        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Country> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable(TableName);
            builder.HasKey(x => x.CountryCode);
            builder.Property(x => x.CountryCode).HasMaxLength(3);
            builder.Property(x => x.CountryName).HasMaxLength(50);

            builder.Property(x => x.CountryCode2).HasMaxLength(2);

            builder.HasData(new Country[]
            {
                new Country { CountryCode = "ARG", CountryName = "Argentina", CountryCode2 = "AR", CountryNumberCode = 32 },
                new Country { CountryCode = "URY", CountryName = "Uruguay", CountryCode2 = "UY", CountryNumberCode = 858 },
                new Country { CountryCode = "CHL", CountryName = "Chile", CountryCode2 = "CL", CountryNumberCode = 152 },
                new Country { CountryCode = "BRA", CountryName = "Brasil", CountryCode2 = "BR", CountryNumberCode = 76 }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Let's us see the IEntityTypeConfiguration implementation

Comment: I've added the final implementation of the interface.